# Android whatsApp integration API unable to find

Tags: android

I want to create an android app from which I can post text to whatsApp from my contacts. I refered a lot of links nothing is clear. No clarification regarding any API or not.

Finally I got [venomous0x/WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI).

They say that its an API. But I am unable to import it into my Eclipse workplace. **How can I do this? Any alternatives?** Please help me guys!!

Comment: There is some mention about it being a proof of concept.I dont think whatsapp has any API which is public.

Comment: It's not an Android library. More like, PHP application from what I observed. And as stated above, there is no public API from WhatsApp itself.

Comment: So how Can I do that guys??Any alternative ways??

Answer (score 1):

For future readers i have done it like this: for ref [WhatsApp doc](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

you can share directly to WhatsApp or hike etc and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using `setPackage` in your `intent`.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```